# using ImageMagick with C++ system call

Tags: c++, imagemagick, command-line-arguments

In my C++ program, I can use ImageMagick commands through the system call. For example, to display an image named button_out.miff, I can put the following code in my program:

```
system("display button_out.miff -display :0");
```

Now I want to pass the image file name "button_out.miff" as a parameter to my c++ program. For example, if my compiled program is named test.exe, I wish when I run the command:

```
test.exe button_out.miff
```

my program can pass button_out.miff as a parameter to the ImageMagick display command. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it’s more about string concatenation?

```
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        string filename = CW2AEX<>(argv[1]);

        stringstream ss;
        ss << "display " << filename << "-display :0";

        system(ss.str().c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add any other parameters to your string the same way, I don’t see any difference.